# How to make upower show correct battery state?

Tags: 15.10, battery, udev, gnome-power-manager, 16.04

Ubuntu battery icon uses about 1-2 minutes before recognizing that the charger is plugged in or not. How to make the battery status update more often so that it recognizes the charger's state immediately.

This problem was not present in Ubuntu 14.10. It appeared in 15.04, and was also present in 15.10. Currently, I am using 16.04 on an early 2014 MacBook Air model.

[image: it says updated and then 99 seconds]

You can see that in the picture it says updated and then 99 seconds.

With charger unplugged, `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` gives me the following output:

```
native-path:          BAT0
vendor:               SMP
model:                bq20z451
power supply:         yes
updated:              fr. 01. jan. 2016 kl. 21.29 +0100 (1 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
  present:             yes
  rechargeable:        yes
  state:               charging
  warning-level:       none
  energy:              19,2888 Wh
  energy-empty:        0 Wh
  energy-full:         48,1992 Wh
  energy-full-design:  54,34 Wh
  energy-rate:         7,3112 W
  voltage:             7,868 V
  time to full:        4,0 hours
  percentage:          36%
  temperature:         32,8 degrees C
  capacity:            88,6993%
  technology:          lithium-ion
  icon-name:          'battery-good-charging-symbolic'
History (charge):
  1451680147    36,000  charging
History (rate):
  1451680164    7,311   charging
  1451680147    24,183  charging
```

Comment: Could you please give the output of this: 'sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name'

Comment: MacBookAir6,2
Invalid entry length (0). DMI table is broken! Stop.

Comment: Okay, now this: acpi -V | grep Battery

Comment: And also: upower -d

Comment: Battery 0: Discharging, 82%, 06:39:27 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 7150 mAh, last full capacity 6249 mAh = 87%
Adapter 0: off-line
Cooling 0: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 1: BAT0 no state information available
Cooling 2: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 3: LCD 80 of 100

Comment: Is your Macbook currently plugged in or is it unplugged?

Comment: unplugged for the moment

Comment: The problem is that when i connect the charger and then unplugs it, it takes up to 5 minutes before the indicator shoes the change

Comment: Okay. Was that the output from acpi or upower?

Comment: I have edited OP with both commands output

Comment: Oh, so your saying that it WILL change but it may take a couple of minutes before you see the change?

Comment: Yeah I think i might have been to unclear(Bad English you know)

Comment: It is not a big deal it just annoys me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33549/discussion-between-max-kulik-and-havard-pettersen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `acpi_osi=` as a kernel parameter fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After working with you in chat it was determined that the plugin was correctly installed and it was working as it should. The minor issue is that the Battery Indicator icon can take anywhere between 2 - 5 minutes to update.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Under older versions of Gnome you were able to follow the steps below to change some of the power-manager settings. However that has been dropped in version 3.1.4. (Further info can be found [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=655298).)

I suggest you try using the "dconf editor". BE VERY CAREFUL while using it!

```
sudo apt-get install -y dconf-editor
```

After installing "dconf-editor" have a look at the section "org" -> "gnome" -> "power-manager" -> "icon-policy"... this also changes the behavior of the battery-icon.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

To **solve** the problem, it is suggested that you use the Unity interface under your system settings to change anything that need be.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The addition of `indicator-power` in Ubuntu overrides the need of `power-manager`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
plymouth reactivated lsb
plymouth reactivated updates lsb
sudo -i
plymouthd
plymouth-upstart-bridge
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Geting errors while trying to run theese commands

Comment: But to long to post

Comment: unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Comment: Trying to rebuild kernel with some configurations, will report if it worked